# Why google chrome return old facebook app_id when i try to social login facebook in wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to integrate the facebook sdk into my custom login form to allow users to log in via social. I think I'm at a good point, the code responds perfectly to the commands but I have a problem.

First of all I'm using google chrome to do various tests. When I click on login with facebook I get the dialog with the message: Sorry, the application you are trying to use does not exist or has been disabled. In fact, I deleted the old facebook login app some time ago. But now I have a new one and I've included it in my project.

When the social login dialog opens, in the address bar I get: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=My_old_key_xxx

Why do I still get old api_key ? I have tried with firefox and this is not happening, in fact, the app works fine and login as expected. I thought it was a cache problem, so I cleared the cache and cookies but the problem persists.

I hope someone can shed some light on this, I appreciate any help.

I leave my Javascript and php code below, I'm working with wordpress and what you see below is a plugin I created especially for my project.

```
// Facebook SDK
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'MY_NEW_APP_ID', //of course i set it up with my facebook app id
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v15.0'
        });
    };
```

PHP Code

```
// Actions Plugin
add_action( 'wp_ajax_login', 'login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_login', 'login_handler' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_facebook_login', 'facebook_login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_login', 'facebook_login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_google_login', 'google_login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_google_login', 'google_login_handler' );

// Shortcodes
add_shortcode('login_form', 'render_login_form');

// LOGIN FORM FUNCTIONS
// Render login-form temlate inside shortcode
function render_login_form(){
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      return __( 'You are already signed in.' );
   } else { 
      $template = require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/login-form.php' );
   }
}

// Ajax action handler for login-form.php
function login_handler() {

   $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];
   $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
   $recaptcha_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
   $recaptcha_data = array(
    'secret' => $recaptcha_secret,
    'response' => $recaptcha_response
   );

   $recaptcha_options = array(
      'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($recaptcha_data)
      )
   );

   $recaptcha_context  = stream_context_create($recaptcha_options);
   $recaptcha_verify = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url, false, $recaptcha_context);
   $recaptcha_response = json_decode($recaptcha_verify);

   if(!$recaptcha_response->success) {
      wp_send_json_error( array('message' => __( 'Invalid reCAPTCHA.', 'text-domain' ) ) );
   }

   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'login-form-nonce' ) ){
      wp_send_json_error( array('message' => __( 'Invalid security token.', 'text-domain' ) ) );
   }
   
   // rest of the login code
   $creds = array();
   $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
   $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
   $creds['remember'] = $_POST['remember'];
   $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
   if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
      wp_send_json_error( array('message' => __( 'Invalid username or password.', 'text-domain' ) ) );
   } else{
      wp_send_json_success();
   }
   wp_die();

}


//** Facebook Login AJAX Handler **/ 
function facebook_login_handler() {
   // Verify ID token
   $facebook_id = $_POST['facebook_id'];
   $access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/' . $facebook_id . '?access_token=' . $access_token );
   $facebook_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

   if ( ! isset( $facebook_response['id'] ) ) {
       $response = array(
           'success' => false,
           'message' => 'Invalid Facebook ID token'
       );
       echo json_encode( $response );
       wp_die();
   }

   // Check if the user already exists in our database
   $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
   if ( ! $user ) {
       $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
   }

   if ( $user ) {
       // Update user meta with Facebook ID
       update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'facebook_id', $facebook_id );
       // Log the user in
       wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
       wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
       $response = array(
           'success' => true,
           'message' => 'Login successful'
       );
   } else {
       // If the user does not exist, create a new account
       $user_data = array(
         'user_login' => $username,
         'user_email' => $email,
         'user_pass' => wp_generate_password()
     );
     $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
     if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
         $response = array(
             'success' => false,
             'message' => $user_id->get_error_message()
         );
         echo json_encode( $response );
         wp_die();
     } else {
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'facebook_id', $facebook_id );
         wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
         wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
         $response = array(
             'success' => true,
             'message' => 'Registration and login successful'
         );
     }
 }
 echo json_encode( $response );
 wp_die();
}

// Google Login AJAX Handler
function google_login_handler() {
 $id_token = $_POST['id_token'];
 $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=' . $id_token );
 $google_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

 if ( ! isset( $google_response['sub'] ) ) {
     $response = array(
         'success' => false,
         'message' => 'Invalid Google ID token'
     );
     echo json_encode( $response );
     wp_die();
 }

 // Check if the user already exists in our database
 $user = get_user_by( 'email', $google_response['email'] );
 if ( $user ) {
     // Update user meta with Google ID
     update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'google_id', $google_response['sub'] );
     // Log the user in
     wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
     wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
     $response = array(
         'success' => true,
         'message' => 'Login successful'
     );
 } else {
     // If the user does not exist, create a new account
     $user_data = array(
         'user_login' => $google_response['email'],
         'user_email' => $google_response['email'],
         'user_pass' => wp_generate_password()
     );
     $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
     if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
         $response = array(
             'success' => false,
             'message' => $user_id->get_error_message()
         );
     } else {
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'google_id', $google_response['sub'] );
         wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
         wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
         $response = array(
             'success' => true,
             'message' => 'Registration and login successful'
         );
     }
 }
 echo json_encode( $response );
 wp_die();
}
```

Javascript and Html Form

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<!-- <div class="social-login">
    <button class="facebook-login">Login con Facebook</button>
    <button class="google-login">Login con Google</button>
</div> -->

<form id="login-form" method="post">
   <label for="username">Username o Email:</label>
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
   <label for="remember">Ricordami</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
   <div id="login-form-message"></div>
   <button type="submit">Accedi</button>
   <div id="facebook-login-button"></div>
   <div id="google-login-button"></div>
</form>


<script>
// Manage Login Form    
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting the normal way
        
        // Add Regex Data validation for input fields email, username and password
        // Add escape with "encodeURIComponent".
        
        var form = $(this);
        var username = encodeURIComponent(form.find('#username').val());
        var email = encodeURIComponent(form.find('#email').val());
        var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$|^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/; 
        var isValid = regex.test(username) || regex.test(email);

        // Error Message if Wrong email or password
        if (!isValid) {
            $('#login-form-message').html("Username o email non validi");
            return;
        }
        
        // Google ReCaptcha Verification
        var recaptcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if(recaptcha_response.length == 0) {
            $('#login-form-message').html("Per favore completa il recaptcha");
            return;
        }

        // Data Object
        var data = {
            'action': 'login',
            'username': username,
            'password': encodeURIComponent(form.find('#password').val()),
            'remember': encodeURIComponent(form.find('#remember').val()),
            'nonce': encodeURIComponent(form.find('input[name="nonce"]').val()),
            'recaptcha_response': recaptcha_response
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#login-form-message').html(response.data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    /* Manage Social Login Script */
    
    // Facebook SDK
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'MY_NEW_APP_ID', //of course i set it up with my facebook app id
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v15.0'
        });
    };

    // Render Facebook Login button
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Utente già connesso, mostra bottone di logout
            document.getElementById('facebook-login-button').innerHTML = '<button id="facebook-logout-button">Logout</button>';
            document.getElementById('facebook-logout-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
                FB.logout(function(response) {
                    location.reload();
                });
            });
        } else {
            // Utente non connesso, mostra bottone di login
            document.getElementById('facebook-login-button').innerHTML = '<button id="facebook-login-button-real">Login with Facebook</button>';
            document.getElementById('facebook-login-button-real').addEventListener('click', function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
                            var data = {
                                'action': 'facebook_login',
                                'facebook_id': response.id,
                                'access_token': FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken,
                                'email': response.email,
                                'username': response.name
                            };
                            jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', data, function(response) {
                                if (response.success) {
                                    location.reload();
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById('login-form-message').innerHTML = response.message;
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('login-form-message').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
                    }
                }, {scope: 'email'});
            });
        }
    });

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Google SDK
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            scope: 'profile email'
        });

        // Render Google Login button
        var googleLoginButton = document.getElementById('google-login-button');
        var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        if (googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
            googleLoginButton.innerHTML = '<button id="google-logout-button">Logout</button>';
            document.getElementById('google-logout-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
                googleAuth.signOut().then(function() {
                    location.reload();
                });
            });
        } else {
            googleLoginButton.innerHTML = '<button id="google-login-button-real">Login with Google</button>';
            document.getElementById('google-login-button-real').addEventListener('click', function() {
                googleAuth.signIn().then(function(googleUser) {
                    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                    var data = {
                        'action': 'google_login',
                        'id_token': id_token
                    };
                    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', data, function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            location.reload();
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('login-form-message').innerHTML = response.message;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and documentation I figured out that the error was the Javascript code. Basically I wasn't defining the ajaxurl variable and some things weren't right. Anyway I leave the updated code below hoping it will be useful to someone who encounters the same problem.

Javascript

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- <div class="social-login">
    <button class="facebook-login">Login con Facebook</button>
    <button class="google-login">Login con Google</button>
</div> -->

<form id="login-form" method="post">
   <label for="username">Username o Email:</label>
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
   <label for="remember">Ricordami</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember">
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="PUT_YOUR_G_RECAPTCHA_KEY"></div>
   <div id="login-form-message"></div>
   <button type="submit">Accedi</button>
</form>
   <button id="facebook-login-button">Accedi con Facebook</button>
   <div id="google-login-button"></div>

<script>
// Manage Login Form    
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting the normal way
        
        // Add Regex Data validation for input fields email, username and password
        // La regex utilizzata in questo esempio è composta da due parti separate da un pipe (|): /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/: Questa parte della regex verifica se l'input è un indirizzo email valido. -- /^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/: Questa parte della regex verifica se l'input è un nome utente valido.
        // Per eseguire l'escape di caratteri speciali viene utilizzato "encodeURIComponent".
        
        var form = $(this);
        var username = encodeURIComponent(form.find('#username').val());
        var email = encodeURIComponent(form.find('#email').val());
        var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$|^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+$/; 
        var isValid = regex.test(username) || regex.test(email);

        // Error Message if Wrong email or password
        if (!isValid) {
            $('#login-form-message').html("Username o email non validi");
            return;
        }
        
        // Google ReCaptcha Verification
        var recaptcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
        if(recaptcha_response.length == 0) {
            $('#login-form-message').html("Per favore completa il recaptcha");
            return;
        }

        // Data Object
        var data = {
            'action': 'login',
            'username': username,
            'password': encodeURIComponent(form.find('#password').val()),
            'remember': encodeURIComponent(form.find('#remember').val()),
            'nonce': encodeURIComponent(form.find('input[name="nonce"]').val()),
            'recaptcha_response': recaptcha_response
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#login-form-message').html(response.data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
  

    /* Manage Social Login Script */
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'PUT_YOUR_APP_ID',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v15.0'
    });
        
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
        document.getElementById('facebook-login-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, function(response) {
                        var data = {
                            'action': 'facebook_login',
                            'facebook_id': response.id,
                            'access_token': FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken,
                            'email': response.email,
                            'username': response.name
                        };
                        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                window.location.href = '/home';
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById('login-form-message').innerHTML = response.message;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                } else { 
                    document.getElementById('login-form-message').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
                }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        });
    }

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Google SDK
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: 'PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            scope: 'profile email'
        });

        // Render Google Login button
        var googleLoginButton = document.getElementById('google-login-button');
        var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        if (googleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
            googleLoginButton.innerHTML = '<button id="google-logout-button">Logout</button>';
            document.getElementById('google-logout-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
                googleAuth.signOut().then(function() {
                    location.reload();
                });
            });
        } else {
            googleLoginButton.innerHTML = '<button id="google-login-button-real">Login with Google</button>';
            document.getElementById('google-login-button-real').addEventListener('click', function() {
                googleAuth.signIn().then(function(googleUser) {
                    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                    var data = {
                        'action': 'google_login',
                        'id_token': id_token
                    };
                    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>', data, function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            location.reload();
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('login-form-message').innerHTML = response.message;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });

});



</script>
```

PHP

```
// Actions Plugin
add_action( 'wp_ajax_login', 'login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_login', 'login_handler' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_facebook_login', 'facebook_login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_login', 'facebook_login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_google_login', 'google_login_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_google_login', 'google_login_handler' );

// Shortcodes
add_shortcode('login_form', 'render_login_form');

// LOGIN FORM FUNCTIONS
// Render login-form temlate inside shortcode
function render_login_form(){
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      return __( 'You are already signed in.' );
   } else { 
      $template = require( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/login-form.php' );
   }
}

// Ajax action handler for login-form.php
function login_handler() {

   $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];
   $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
   $recaptcha_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
   $recaptcha_data = array(
    'secret' => $recaptcha_secret,
    'response' => $recaptcha_response
   );

   $recaptcha_options = array(
      'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($recaptcha_data)
      )
   );

   $recaptcha_context  = stream_context_create($recaptcha_options);
   $recaptcha_verify = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url, false, $recaptcha_context);
   $recaptcha_response = json_decode($recaptcha_verify);

   if(!$recaptcha_response->success) {
      wp_send_json_error( array('message' => __( 'Invalid reCAPTCHA.', 'text-domain' ) ) );
   }

   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'login-form-nonce' ) ){
      wp_send_json_error( array('message' => __( 'Invalid security token.', 'text-domain' ) ) );
   }
   
   // rest of the login code
   $creds = array();
   $creds['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
   $creds['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
   $creds['remember'] = $_POST['remember'];
   $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
   if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
      wp_send_json_error( array('message' => __( 'Invalid username or password.', 'text-domain' ) ) );
   } else{
      wp_send_json_success();
   }
   wp_die();

}


//** Facebook Login AJAX Handler **/ 
function facebook_login_handler() {
   // Verify ID token
   $facebook_id = $_POST['facebook_id'];
   $access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/' . $facebook_id . '?access_token=' . $access_token );
   $facebook_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

   if ( ! isset( $facebook_response['id'] ) ) {
       $response = array(
           'success' => false,
           'message' => 'Invalid Facebook ID token'
       );
       echo json_encode( $response );
       wp_die();
   }

   // Check if the user already exists in our database
   $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
   if ( ! $user ) {
       $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
   }

   if ( $user ) {
       // Update user meta with Facebook ID
       update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'facebook_id', $facebook_id );
       // Log the user in
       wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
       wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
       $response = array(
           'success' => true,
           'message' => 'Login successful'
       );
   } else {
       // If the user does not exist, create a new account
       $user_data = array(
         'user_login' => $username,
         'user_email' => $email,
         'user_pass' => wp_generate_password()
     );
     $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
     if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
         $response = array(
             'success' => false,
             'message' => $user_id->get_error_message()
         );
         echo json_encode( $response );
         wp_die();
     } else {
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'facebook_id', $facebook_id );
         wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
         wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
         $response = array(
             'success' => true,
             'message' => 'Registration and login successful'
         );
     }
 }
 echo json_encode( $response );

 wp_die();
}

// Google Login AJAX Handler
function google_login_handler() {
 $id_token = $_POST['id_token'];
 $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=' . $id_token );
 $google_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

 if ( ! isset( $google_response['sub'] ) ) {
     $response = array(
         'success' => false,
         'message' => 'Invalid Google ID token'
     );
     echo json_encode( $response );
     wp_die();
 }

 // Check if the user already exists in our database
 $user = get_user_by( 'email', $google_response['email'] );
 if ( $user ) {
     // Update user meta with Google ID
     update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'google_id', $google_response['sub'] );
     // Log the user in
     wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
     wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
     $response = array(
         'success' => true,
         'message' => 'Login successful'
     );
 } else {
     // If the user does not exist, create a new account
     $user_data = array(
         'user_login' => $google_response['email'],
         'user_email' => $google_response['email'],
         'user_pass' => wp_generate_password()
     );
     $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
     if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
         $response = array(
             'success' => false,
             'message' => $user_id->get_error_message()
         );
     } else {
         update_user_meta( $user_id, 'google_id', $google_response['sub'] );
         wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
         wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
         $response = array(
             'success' => true,
             'message' => 'Registration and login successful'
         );
     }
 }
 echo json_encode( $response );
 wp_die();
}
```